# Proving matrix equality $(K_{n,n}\otimes I_n)a^{\otimes3}=a^{\otimes3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, kronecker-product

How to prove the matrix equality $(K_{n,n}\otimes I_n)a^{\otimes3}=a^{\otimes3}$?

Here $K_{n,n}$ is a $n^2\times n^2$ commutation matrix, $I_n$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix and $a$ is a $n\times1$ vector, $\otimes$ denotes the kronecker product and $a^{\otimes3}$ is defined as $a\otimes(a\otimes a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commutation matrix (based on [what I found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix)) satisfies $K_{n,n}(u \otimes v) = v \otimes u$ for any $n \times 1$ vectors $u,v$.

Noting that the Kronecker product is associative, we may compute
$$
(K_{n,n} \otimes I) a^{\otimes 3} = (K_{n,n} \otimes I)((a \otimes a) \otimes a) = (K_{n,n} (a \otimes a)) \otimes (I a) = (a \otimes a) \otimes a
$$

---

In response to the comment: note that
$$
K_{n,n}(u \otimes v) = K_{n,n}(\operatorname{vec}(vu^T))
= \operatorname{vec}([vu^T]^T)
= \operatorname{vec}(uv^T) = v \otimes u 
$$
where vec denotes the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

Comment: Why does K_{n,n}(u⊗v)=v⊗u hold?

Comment: @user570271 see my latest edit